# Ul in two columns, which one (or multiple) li's being full width

Tags: html, css

In my demo below, I'm trying to make `.list__li--first` span the width of the two columns.

```css
.list{
  max-width: 400px;
}

.list__ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  columns: 2;
}

.list__li{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.list__li--first{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">

  <ul class="list__ul">
    <li class="list__li list__li--first">Label</li>
    <li class="list__li">Link</li>
    <li class="list__li">Link</li>
    <li class="list__li">Link</li>
    <li class="list__li">Link</li>
    <li class="list__li">Link</li>
    <li class="list__li">Link</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

"label" should sit on top of the "links". `width: 100%` doesn't work and I can't see any solutions which also involves `columns`?

Comment: The label doesn't seem like it should be part of the list. Place it outside of the list as a separate element.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier - Unfortunately cannot move the label outside of the `ul`. I'm working within the parameters of `hubspot`, the menu markup renders labels within `li` elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS-Grid can do that:

```css
.list {
  max-width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.list__ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.list__li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.list__li--first {
  grid-column: span 2;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">

  <ul class="list__ul">
    <li class="list__li list__li--first">Label</li>
    <li class="list__li">Link</li>
    <li class="list__li">Link</li>
    <li class="list__li">Link</li>
    <li class="list__li">Link</li>
    <li class="list__li">Link</li>
    <li class="list__li">Link</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```